# Counting elements of a particular order in Dihedral groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Find the number of elements of order $1$, $2$, $5$ and $10$ in $D_{10}$.

I want to decompose the group into $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ and then use my knowledge of cyclic groups, but I know this is incorrect because $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ is Abelian and $D_{10}$ is not. I have seen some references to Sylow's theorem on the website, but we haven't learned this yet. How to proceed?

Comment: $D_{10}$ is quite a small group. You can take each element in turn, and find its order, and that won't take you very long.

Comment: anyway that's not brute force?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this was to recognize that all elements were rotations or order 2 flips. So count rotations as you would in $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$, then add $n$ more order 2 elements (the reflections).